# Calcular factorial en Python

Tags: python, factorial

Estoy iniciándome en Python, y tengo un pequeño script que calcula el factorial de un número:

```js
a = 2

def calculaFactorial(n):
    if n:
         n = n * calculaFactorial(n - 1)
    else:
         return n

factorial_a = calculaFactorial(a)
print(f"El factorial de {a} es {factorial_a}")
```

Sin embargo dice que la sintaxis del else es incorrecta:

```
C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop>python factorial.py


File "factorial.py", line 6
    else:
        ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
```

¿Por qué?

Comment: No se mucho de Python pero en el if esos dos puntos es que es true o te falta poner if n == != que?

Comment: Si has notado, python no usa llaves ni 'end' para identificar los bucles, si no en tabulaciones. Esto fue así para que el código fuera forzosamente ordenado. Esas tabulaciones pueden ser tabulaciones como tal (Tab), o espacios. Es más aceptado de forma generalizada que sean 4 espacios por nivel. No se pueden combinar espacios con tabulaciones porque aparece el error que describes. En tu editor de código configúralo que convierta las tabulaciones de python en espacios y también que muestre los espacios y las tabulaciones para corregirlos cuando aparecen.

Comment: gracias @aeportugal, no había tenido eso en cuenta.

Comment: Hasta donde yo se @Juan, cualquier número mayor que 0 en Python es identificado como un valor booleano == true, de ahí que haya puesto el número directamente en el if como condición a analizar.  Aquí tienes un ejemplo de ello : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_if_else.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema es la identación en tu código:

> File "factorial.py", line 6
>       else:
>           ^ TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Podrías usar un editor como Sublime Text que facilita escribir el código.

```
a = 5

def calculaFactorial(n):
  if n>0:
    n = n * calculaFactorial(n - 1)
  else:
    n = 1
  return n

factorial_a = calculaFactorial(a)
print "El factorial de ", a ,"es ",factorial_a
```

Comment: Estoy usando python2.7

Answer (score 1):

## Una forma de calcular el factorial en Python3 sería:

```python3
# Definimos la variable
num = 6

# Definimos la función factorial(n), donde «n» es el número 
# al que se le calculará su factorial
def factorial(n):
    # Cuando 'n' sea equivalente a 0 (n == 0), entonces retornará 1. Si tomamos en cuenta 
    # que por convenio 0! es equivalente a 1, entonces se multiplicará por el resto.

    # Es decir: el factorial 6! = 6 x 5 x 4 x 3 x 2 x 1 = 720, pero si llega a 0, entonces seguirá
    # siendo 720.
    if n == 0:
        return 1;

    # Mientras no sea cero (0) realizará una operación matemática de tipo recursiva.
    else:
        return n * factorial(n - 1);


x = factorial(num)
print(x); # 720
```

> ### Importante
>
> En Python, la indentación forma parte del lenguaje. Se debe tener siempre presente.

#### Ahora bien

Podemos mejorar el código, para cuando se ingrese un valor negativo:

```python3
# Definimos la variable
num = -6

# Definimos la función factorial(n), donde «n» es el número 
# al que se le calculará su factorial
def factorial(n):
    # Cuando 'n' sea equivalente a 0 (n == 0), entonces retornará 1. Si tomamos en cuenta 
    # que por convenio 0! es equivalente a 1, entonces se multiplicará por el resto.

    # Es decir: el factorial 6! = 6 x 5 x 4 x 3 x 2 x 1 = 720, pero si llega a 0, entonces seguirá
    # siendo 720.
    if n == 0:
        return 1

    # Si el usuario ha ingresado un valor negativo
    elif n < 0:
        return (n * factorial(-n - 1))

    # Mientras no sea cero (0) realizará una operación matemática de tipo recursiva.
    else:
        return n * factorial(n - 1)


x = factorial(num)
print(x); # -720
```

### Veamos algo de teoría:

1. **Recursividad**:

   > El poder de la recursión evidentemente se fundamenta en la posibilidad de definir un conjunto infinito de objetos con una declaración finita. Igualmente, un número infinito de operaciones computacionales puede describirse con un programa recursivo finito, incluso en el caso de que este programa no contenga repeticiones explícitas.
   >
   > **Fuente** [*Wikipedia*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursi%C3%B3n_(ciencias_de_computaci%C3%B3n))
2. **Factorial**

   > El factorial de un entero positivo n, el factorial de n o n factorial se define en principio como el producto de todos los números enteros positivos desde 1 (es decir, los números naturales) hasta n. Por ejemplo:
   >       `5! = 1 x 2 x 3 x 4 x 5`
   >
   > **Fuente**: [*Wikipedia*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial)

Comment: Hay que tomar en cuenta que esta respuesta se puede mejorar. No es perfecta, pero sí mejorable.

Answer (score 1):

estoy aprendiendo a programar en Python recién llevo pocas horas de aprendizaje y logré hacer mi primer programa sin copiar nada de otro, para calcular el factorial de un número (solo falta poner una condición if para limitar el número si se quiere). Les comparto el código:

```
print("\nFACTORIAL DE UN NUMERO")
print("\n Este programa calcula el factorial de un número")

numero = int(input("Ingresa un número: "))
contador = 0
fact = 1

for contador in range(1,(numero+1)):
    fact = contador * fact
print(f"El factorial del número {numero} es {str(fact)}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Este es el Factorial de un numero en python:

```
def factorial(x,n):
 if(n>0):
  x=factorial(x,n-1)
  x=x*n
 else:
  x=1
 return x
n=int(input("ingresa un numero  \n"))
x=1
x=factorial(x,n)
print (x)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = int(input("Ingrese un número entero y positivo para calcular su factorial: "))
n = 0
z = x

while (n + 1) < z:
    x = x * (n + 1)
    n = n + 1

if x == 0:
    print("El resultado de 0! es 1")
else:
    print("El resultado de " + str(z) + "! es " + str(x))
```

Comment: Bienvenio a SOes. Te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer todo lo que puedas del [help]. Porfavor agrega una explicacion acerca de como es tu respuesta diferente a las demas.

Comment: Las respuestas que tienen solo código, sin explicar cual es el problema o cómo el código resuelve la pregunta son generalmente consideradas de baja calidad. Por favor lee [answer].

Answer (score 0):

```
def factorial(x):
'''
  La función impar(n) devuelve:
  -  True: si número es impar
  - False: si número no es impar
  >>> factorial(0)
  1
  >>> factorial(1)
  1
  >>> factorial(3)
  6
  >>> factorial(-4)
  1

'''


factorial=1
for i in range (1,x+1):
  factorial=factorial*i
return factorial
```